# Как изменится смысл предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, меняется ли значение текста при наличии и отсутствии запятой после слова "заведениях" в предложении с союзом "а также".

*Дополнительно засчитывается время их обучения (независимо от формы обучения) в гражданских высших учебных заведениях, а также в других учебных заведениях, после окончания которых присваивается офицерское (специальное) звание.*

*Дополнительно засчитывается время их обучения (независимо от формы обучения) в гражданских высших учебных заведениях, а также в других учебных заведениях после окончания которых присваивается офицерское (специальное) звание.*

Answer (score 1):

Простите, но, согласно нормам пунктуации, допустим только один вариант — с запятой, которой Вы обособляете последнее придаточное в сложном предложении.

Comment: Тогда задам вопрос по другому: выражение "после окончания которых присваивается офицерское (специальное) звание" относится: 1) только к "другим учебным заведениям" или 2) одновременно и к "гражданским высшим учебным заведениям"  и к "другим учебным заведениям"

Comment: Только к "другим".

Answer (score 0):

**Грамматически здесь не определяется, к каким учебным заведениям относится придаточное предложение,** поэтому это нужно делать по смыслу, путем логических рассуждений.

Ответы на вопросы в качестве варианта:

В гражданских высших учебных заведениях присваивается офицерское (специальное) звание? Присваивается, но не во всех.

В других (каких-то ещё) учебных заведениях может присваиваться офицерское (специальное) звание? Да, существуют такие.

**Тогда, скорее всего, придаточное относится и к тем, и к другим.** Таким образом, время не засчитывается, если в гражданском вузе вы не получили офицерское звание. И оно засчитывается, если вы  получили звание в каком-либо другом учебном заведении.

Comment: Рассуждение: зачем нужно было выделять "гражданские высшие учебные заведения"? ведь можно было написать проще.  
          "Дополнительно засчитывается время их обучения (независимо от формы обучения) в учебных заведениях после окончания которых присваивается офицерское (специальное) звание."    (ведь понятие "другие учебные заведения" - включает в себя ВСЕ учебные заведения")

Comment: Ну да, вы правы, формально здесь оба варианта возможны, поэтому текст желательно отредактировать. Но  мне кажется, что сообщение прежде всего касается именно вузов с военной кафедрой, где присваивается звание, Предлог А ТАКЖЕ - присоединительный, он дополнительно включает другие учебные заведения, кроме вузов.